# Tp-link TL-SG116 ethernet jack leds meaning

Tags: switch, led

I have a tp-link TL-SG116 16 port switch. Some of the devices connected to it make the corresponsing jack leds to blink green, while others- amber. I cannot figure out the pattern here. Its not about being a 100 Mbit or 1000 Mbit device. The datasheet does not say anything about it.

[image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

Comment: Why doesn't the pattern fit? Orange 100base-T, green 1000base-T, flashing == data passing. Note that if any of those cables links from another node or router, then all lights will flash as data passes from that one.

Comment: You might be right. What fooled me was that one pc is blinking orange when its turned off, but starts to blink green when the OS boots...

Comment: Pure guess - it may have a WoL mode which doesn't need the full speed, as it's only waiting for one small event.

Comment: The colour is yellow not amber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Some of the devices connected to it make the corresponding jack LEDs to blink green, while others blink yellow.

It's documented in the [Installation Guide](https://static.tp-link.com/upload/manual/2022/202206/20220620/7106509649_TL-SG108(UN)_IG.pdf):

> [image]